# how can i convert bitmap image to drawable image so that it will be show over another bitmap image

Tags: java, android

**i've a class which extends view ...in which i have two bitmap  images to show one over another ....for this im am trying to convert one bitmap image to a drawable image but it dsnt show over the first one what i'm trying this is.....**

```
public class ShowCanvas extends View {

Bitmap CanvasBitmap;
Bitmap ScaledBitmap;
Bitmap smallbitmap;
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

private Drawable mImage;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;



public ShowCanvas(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    ScaledBitmap = DrawView.scaled;



**when i get the image from drawable it shows over the first one...**
```

mImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dress01);

**but when i'm using this it dsnt shows image...**

mImage = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Dress.bitmap);

```
    System.out.println("Drawable" + mImage);



    int X = mImage.getMinimumWidth();

    int Y = mImage.getIntrinsicHeight();

    System.out.println(" Rough" + X + "\t" + Y);


    mImage.setBounds(0, 0, mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());

}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CanvasBitmap = bitmap;

    System.out.println("CanvasBitmap" + CanvasBitmap);

    int X = CanvasBitmap.getHeight();
    int Y = CanvasBitmap.getWidth();

    System.out.println("CanvasBitmap " + X + "\t" + Y);

}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Paint mpaint = new Paint();
    canvas.save();

    canvas.drawBitmap(ScaledBitmap, 0, 0, mpaint);

    mImage.draw(canvas);

    Log.i("Debug", "mImage.draw(canvas)");

    canvas.restore();

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

```
Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

use this to convert bitmap image to drawable.